# SemanticException [Error 10014] Hive UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, user-defined-functions

i'm using apache hive with and UDF function create in eclipse. So when i call the function in my sql query, i see this error:

FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10014]: Line 1:7 Wrong arguments 'summary': No matching method for class HiveUDF.TokenizeString with (string). Possible choices:

Where is the problem?

UDF CLASS

```
package HiveUDF;
public class TokenizeString extends UDF {

public List<String> tokenize (Text text) {
    List<String> prova = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(text == null)
        return null;
    String[] words = text.toString().split("\\n");
    for (String w : words)
        prova.add(w);
    return prova;
}
```

}

SQL TABLE AND QUERY

```
id                      bigint                                      
productid               string                                      
userid                  string                                      
profilename             string                                      
helpfulnessnumerator    int                                         
helpfulnessdenominator  int                                         
score                   float                                       
time                    int                                         
summary                 string                                      
text                    string

CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION tokenize_summary as 'HiveUDF.TokenizeString';

select tokenize_summary(summary) from amazonproduct;
```

Comment: the method must be named `evaluate`

Answer (score 0):

when you extend UDF class, you must override evaluate(-) method.

Comment: you need to provide some more explanation to support your proposition.

Comment: there is no evaluate in base class to be overridden , we just need to 'provide' the method called 'evaluate' since hive will invoke this method -- it's not about overriding any base method.

Answer (score 0):

```
package HiveUDF;
public class TokenizeString extends UDF {
public List<String> evaulate (Text text) {
    List<String> prova = new ArrayList<String>();
    if(text == null)
        return null;
    String[] words = text.toString().split("\\n");
    for (String w : words)
        prova.add(w);
    return prova;
}
}
```

try this ...

Comment: Please don't add another answer to add more information to your existing answer. Instead, use the `edit` link underneath your first answer to add the information to that answer instead. Please combine your two answers and then delete one of them.